# Test passes without 'beforeEach', but fails with injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have created a web app and trys to test my JavaScript with Karma & Jasmine. My Test looks like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: LoginController', function () {

   // load the controller's module
   beforeEach(module('login'));

   var MainCtrl,
       scope;

   // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
   beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
       scope = $rootScope.$new();
       MainCtrl = $controller('LoginController', {
           $scope: scope
       });
   }));

   it('true is of course true', function () {
       expect(true).toBe(true);
   });
});
```

I placed the following in my karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
  './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  './node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  './app.js',
  './login/LoginController.js',
  './tests/*.js',
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Safari'],

plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-safari-launcher'
],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: true,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

When i run my test without the part from //load the controller's module to the "it" case, it passes. But with it i get an error and the following in my terminal:
`node_modules/angular/angular.js:68:32
        node_modules/angular/angular.js:4640:30
        forEach@node_modules/angular/angular.js:321:24
        loadModules@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4601:12
        createInjector@node_modules/angular/angular.js:4523:30
        workFn@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:60
        loaded@http://localhost:9877/context.js:151:17`

Im new to angular, jasmine and karma, and have tried to search my way through som other questions, but nothing works. Any ideas og what might help?

Comment: Looks like path to the './login/LoginController.js' is incorrect.

Comment: How do you declare your login-module?

Comment: var buboApp = angular.module('login', ['httpService','logService', 'vButton', 'ngNotify']);
 This is the login Module, with the buboApp.controller('LoginController', ... to follow. My LoginController is in a login folder in the root of the directory. Is that the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I dont see you telling karma to include modules that your login module depends on. That is probably the reason tests are failing when angular tries to initialize your module in beforeEach.

Comment: My Controller is depending on my two services and v-button and ng notify. All included in karma.conf.js.. Still error.

Comment: Wait, are `httpService` and `logService` actually services or modules?

Comment: They are a module().service... Im not quite sure what the difference here are. Some way it works now, but i now have a problem with accessing the rootScope variables. But thanks!

Comment: You can't specify actual services in your module's dependencies. Modules can depend on other modules only.